# Lambda expression used inside Include is not valid in Entity Framework Core

Tags: c#, sql, postgresql, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I want to do query in EntityFramework Core 3.1

This is my query:

```
return await context_client.Tbcategoriapregunta.Include(e => e.Tbpreguntasfrecuentes.Where(preguntas => preguntas.Dstipousuario == user)).ToListAsync();
```

But not works, this the message error

```
Lambda expression used inside Include is not valid.
```

This is de message StackTrace

> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.NavigationExpandingExpressionVisitor.ProcessInclude(NavigationExpansionExpression source, Expression expression, Boolean thenInclude)
>      at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.NavigationExpandingExpressionVisitor.VisitMethodCall(MethodCallExpression methodCallExpression)
>      at System.Linq.Expressions.MethodCallExpression.Accept(ExpressionVisitor visitor)
>      at System.Linq.Expressions.ExpressionVisitor.Visit(Expression node)
>      at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.NavigationExpandingExpressionVisitor.Expand(Expression query)
>      at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.QueryTranslationPreprocessor.Process(Expression query)
>      at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.QueryCompilationContext.CreateQueryExecutor[TResult](Expression query)
>      at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.Database.CompileQuery[TResult](Expression query, Boolean async)
>      at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryCompiler.CompileQueryCore[TResult](IDatabase database, Expression query, IModel model, Boolean async)
>      at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryCompiler.<>c__DisplayClass12_0`1.<ExecuteAsync>b__0()
>      at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.CompiledQueryCache.GetOrAddQueryCore[TFunc](Object cacheKey, Func`1 compiler)
>      at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.CompiledQueryCache.GetOrAddQuery[TResult](Object cacheKey, Func`1 compiler)
>      at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryCompiler.ExecuteAsync[TResult](Expression query, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
>      at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.EntityQueryProvider.ExecuteAsync[TResult](Expression expression, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
>      at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.EntityQueryable`1.GetAsyncEnumerator(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
>      at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.EntityFrameworkQueryableExtensions.IncludableQueryable`2.GetAsyncEnumerator(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredCancelableAsyncEnumerable`1.GetAsyncEnumerator()
>      at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.EntityFrameworkQueryableExtensions.d__64`1.MoveNext()
>      at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
>      at Business.Implementation.BsCategoriaPregunta.d__4.MoveNext() in C:\Users\admin\source\repos\API013-Ayuda\Business\Implementation\BsCategoriaPregunta.cs:line 58

Any idea...???

Answer (score 0):

The purpose of `Include()` is to tell it to load data from a related table at the same time that this query is processed.

The example in [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data) uses a scenario where you want to load a list of blogs from the database and also include the posts related to each blog:

```
using (var context = new BloggingContext())
{
    var blogs = context.Blogs
        .Include(blog => blog.Posts)
        .ToList();
}
```

So it would not make sense to have a `Where()` inside `Include()`.

You will have to tell us what you are trying to do. But maybe something like this might work?

```
return await context_client.Tbcategoriapregunta
    .Include(e => e.Tbpreguntasfrecuentes)
    .Where(categoria => categoria.Tbpreguntasfrecuentes.Dstipousuario == user)
    .ToListAsync();
```